# drop type by variable in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I drop a type by using variable in MSSQL?
I can't drop it in the following way:

```
create procedure DropSomething(
@tName nvarchar(1000)
, @tCode nvarchar(1000)
)
as
begin
    set nocount on
    if @tCode = 'type'
    begin
        if exists(select [name] from sys.types where [name] = @tName) 
        drop type @tName
    end     
end
go   

exec DropSomething N'typeName','type'
```

Here is the error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DropSomething, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 19]
>   The syntax near '@tName' is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't parameterize identifiers in SQL. Parameters are placeholders for data, and identifiers are not data.

You need to use dynamic SQL:

```
if @tCode = 'type'
begin
    if exists(select [name] from sys.types where [name] = @tName) 
    begin
        declare @sql nvarchar(200) = 'drop type ' + QUOTENAME(@tName)
        exec(@sql)
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi Zohar Peled,
It's successful, thank you for your help!

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Comment: And if the type name has spaces in it?

Comment: @TT. Good point. Didn't think about that. I seem to forger people have the habit of using stupid names :-)

Comment: Hi @ZoharPeled ,
It will have the error message:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DropSomething, Line 21 [Batch Start Line 18]
The syntax near 'QUOTENAME' is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server has some quirks when concatenating strings inside `exec`. You simply need to prepare the sql statement first and exec later, by adding another variable. Edited my answer.

Comment: Hi @ZoharPeled,  
Should it will be :   
`declare @sql nvarchar(200) = QUOTENAME(@tName)   
exec('drop type ' + @sql)`